# How to select a block of code in SQL server "new query" window

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there any way to select the entire block with a keyboard shortcut or any method quicker than manual selecting the block.

[image: click for image]

Comment: You could collapse the block to make it easier to select it but it seems kind of silly.

Comment: You can do it with some 3rd party stuff but I'm not aware of a way that is native to SSMS.

Comment: just idea: play with find/bookmark all, Ctrl-K+Ctrl-N for next bookmark + bindings for Edit.ToggleAllOutlining and ToggleOutliningExpansion for SQL Query Editor in Options\Environment\Keyboard

Comment: or use steps (after bound key Ctrl+; for ToggleOutliningExpansion): 1) put cursor on `create` 2) Ctrl+; 3) Home 4) Shift+Down

Comment: perhaps I am missing something, but Ctrl+A selects the entire thing in SSMS